# Avoiding Web service call from other domain in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How do i avoid calling a webservice from other domain?

I want my webservices to be hidden from other projects / domain?

Comment: Seriously, was there just a homework assignment on this?  Literally *the next question in my list* was the very same question, asked by another user seconds before this one.

Comment: Great, you managed to do it without efforts( against the Same-Origin Policy). Normally question is how to make cross-domain service calls in jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Web Services can be checked form the firewall where request is coming. It can checked by the content-type of the response. All webservices have "application/soap-xml" as content-type.

Answer (score 0):

**Authenticate** all your requests to your functions and reject the calls that are not authenticated. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622459/block-cross-domain-calls-to-asp-net-asmx-web-service) for more.